# drupal 7 pagination

Tags: 7, paging

I used the below code but it gives me error. Below is my code:
   `if(isset($_GET['tid']))
        {
         $id=($_GET['tid']);
         $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
         $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
         $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'escorts_product');
         $query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
         $query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid', $id,'=');
         $result = $query->execute();
         $total=count($result);
function pager_default_initialize($total, $limit = 2, $element = 0)
        { 
         global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
         $page = pager_find_page($element);
         $pager_total_items[$element] = $total;//total items
         $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
         $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min($page, ((int) $pager_total[$element]) -1));
         $pager_limits[$element] = $limit;
         return $pager_page_array[$element];
         //print "<pre>";print_r($pager_page_array[$element]);
         }
         print theme('pager', array('quantity',count($result)));` 
error on this line 
`function pager_default_initialize($total, $limit = 2, $element = 0)`
,can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting?

Comment: "Can not redeclare pager_default_initialize", I think it is already declared just need to call this, I also call this by just writing       `pager_default_initialize($total, $limit = 2, $element = 0);`                                                      , error is not appearing now but also not paging?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a parenthesis } before the line: function pager_default_initialize($total, $limit = 2, $element = 0).

Please put it and check the result.

Comment: Thanku @Nilesh, error is fixed but paging not appearing.

Comment: You are welcome, Here you have define the function: function pager_default_initialize($total, $limit = 2, $element = 0) but where you have called that function? You will need to call it at appropriate place.

Comment: I have my custom template file `product-categoies.tpl.php`, after defining I used                                                  `$offset = ($page) * $limit;
 $last = ($offset + $limit <$total)?$offset+$limit:$total;
 $pg=printtheme('pager',array('quantity',count($result)));`